# How do I log what people type in a textbox with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple to-do list project with an HTML text box where you type in a task and it's displayed on screen, however I don't know how to log what someone types so it can be displayed on the screen.

I've thought of recording the info in an array but, I still don't know how to actually log what is typed in the text box.

```
<div id="newList">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your task here" id="task1"/>
  <div id="addBut"></div>
  <div id="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Post your current javascript code. Without that nobody can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @KHansen There is no code because I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

if you just want to log to the console:

```
    let input = Document.getElementById("task1");
    input.addEventListener("keydown",(e) =>{
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
    });
```

if you want to display in the screen:

```
    let input = Document.getElementById("task1");
    let div = Document.getElementById("item");
    input.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        div.innerHTML(e.currentTarget.value)
    })
```

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is good for Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onkeyup` function on your input.

```js
function logChanges(id){
 var x = document.getElementById(id).value;
 console.log(x)
}
```

```html
<div id="newList">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your task here" id="task1" onkeyup="logChanges('task1')"/>
 <div id="addBut"></div>
 <div id="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohhhh okay I get it, now I'd just need to make it so it displays it when you hit a button.

Comment: If you want the value of the input only when the user finish typing, you can use `onchange` instead of `onkeyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a javascript file to go with this html?

You'll need to at least add a `<script>` tag to your hmtl file for writing the javascript in.

Once you have that though, you could try adding an eventListener to the input field, and watching their keystrokes.
(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

ex/

```
var input = document.getElementById('task1'); //grab your input element

input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => { //attached a function to the 'keydown' event which will allow you to change how their keystrokes are handled


    switch(event.keyCode){
        case 13: //they pressed enter
            alert(event.target.innerText); // with the contents of the input
        default:
            break;
    }
})
```

Comment: Does "switch" mean they pressed the key?

Comment: @TheNuthouse the whole function only gets executed once they've pressed a key. the "switch" is a way of handling multiple different "keyCodes" elegantly (ex/ if they press the "enter" key (13) you might want to handle it differently than the letter "A" key.

In this case, it's just popping up an alert box full of the text from the input when they press "enter" in the input.

The switch here could've been just an "if" statement instead -- but that's kind of beside the point.

Comment: reminder to accept an answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it when you hit a button like the code below does :

```js
function showTextInLog() {
    var task1 = document.getElementById('task1');
    console.log(task1.value);
}
```

```html
<div id="newList">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your task here" id="task1"/>
  <div id="addBut"></div>
  <div id="item"></div>
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="showTextInLog();" />
</div>
```